# How to fetch date from mongo dB using node js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

```
{
    status: true,
    paymentDone: true,
    type: 'MANUAL',
    _isJobExecuted: false,
    _isDeleted: false,
    _id: 60139d379fdac790a598316f,
    expiry_date: 2021-02-28T17:42:55.073Z,
    _isExecutedTime: 2021-01-29T00:00:00.000Z,
     createdAt: 2021-01-29T05:29:27.257Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-01-29T05:29:27.257Z,
    __v: 0,
    id: '60139d379fdac790a598316f',
    subscription: null,
    package: null,
    user: null
  },
let sub = subscriptionInstance.expired_date;
```

this is not working ,getting undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Please elaborate a little more about the question, the object you define first with all keys are coming from mongo-DB or you create it statically.
if you creating the object statically then you can access the key in this way.

```
const subscriptionInstance={
status: true,
paymentDone: true,
type: 'MANUAL',
_isJobExecuted: false,
_isDeleted: false,
_id: 60139d379fdac790a598316f,
expiry_date: 2021-02-28T17:42:55.073Z,
_isExecutedTime: 2021-01-29T00:00:00.000Z,
 createdAt: 2021-01-29T05:29:27.257Z,
updatedAt: 2021-01-29T05:29:27.257Z,
__v: 0,
id: '60139d379fdac790a598316f',
subscription: null,
package: null,
user: null
},
let sub = subscriptionInstance.expired_date;
```